# Prove that $x = uy$ for some unit $u \in R^{\times}$ iff $(x)=(y)$ as ideals.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, principal-ideal-domains

Prove that:In a commutative ring $R,$ $x = uy$ for some unit $u \in R^{\times}$ iff $(x)=(y)$ as ideals.

**My thoughts:**

I feel like the idea is similar to the proof of the following proposition:

**Proposition.** Let $I$ be a left or right ideal of a ring $R$ with unity.
Then $I = R$ *if and only* if $I$ contains *a unit*.

*Proof:* Let $I$ be a left ideal of $R$. If $I = R$ then $1 \in I$, so $I$ contains a unit.
Conversely, if $u \in I$ is any unit, let $u^{-1}$ be its inverse.
For any $r \in R$, we have $r = r (u^{-1} u) = (r u^{-1}) u \in I$, because $I$ is a left ideal. Thus $I = R$. This logic is easily adapted for right ideals to show the same result. Certainly it then is true for two-sided ideals and ideals of unital commutative rings.

**But still I do not know how to write a rigor proof, could anyone help me in doing so please?**

Comment: You will find from the duplicate that "$(x)=(y)$ implies associate" (in your sense, as unit multiples of each other) is false.

Comment: but it is correct if we are in an integral domain ..... am I correct? @rschwieb

Comment: Yes, for an integral domain it is correct.

Comment: @rschwieb that is all what I need ..... thank u!

Comment: The answer for domains would also be available on the site in a search.